# Keep not null values from many datframe rows

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where some order numbers have more than one row, but these multiple rows don't have access data just nulls at some cases, I want to keep the non null values and condense them all to one row.

here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ORDER_NUMBER'] = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
df['date1'] = [11, np.nan, 12, np.nan]    
df['date2'] = [np.nan, 13, np.nan, 14]

ORDER_NUMBER    date1   date2
       0    a   11.0    NaN
       1    a   NaN     13.0
       2    b   12.0    NaN
       3    b   NaN     14.0
```

I want this:

```
    ORDER_NUMBER    date1   date2           
              a     11.0    13.0
              b     12.0    14.0
```

so far I have:

```
df.groupby('ORDER_NUMBER').apply(lambda df: df.fillna(method='ffill').iloc[-1:])
```

This works, but it is extremely inefficient (my df ia about 200K, 5 and it takes about 20 minutes)

any ideas?

Comment: `df.groupby('ORDER_NUMBER',as_index=False).first()` ?

Comment: looks good, seems to be exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a dupe(*can't find any so answering*):

You can use [`groupby().first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) here:

```
df.groupby('ORDER_NUMBER',as_index=False).first()
```

---

```
  ORDER_NUMBER  date1  date2
0            a   11.0   13.0
1            b   12.0   14.0
```